# Getting the names of files in the folder

Tags: java

Decided to put the question differently, suppose we have a file-test, there is a lot of different files, some of this type indeks.html, kiki.tht, lololo.bin and so on, to get the names of all files in a folder, you can use this code:

```
File folder = new File("C:\\test\\");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
```

But how to display only the file name without the extension? Indeks.html looolo.tht not like (just remember files in the lot, there is no duplicate names), and the index and looolo)

Comment: Was anything wrong with the answer you got to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381253/output-files-from-the-folder-with-no-extension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
int index = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (index >= 0) {
    fileName = fileName.substring(0,  index);
}
System.out.println(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String fullName = file.getName();
String nameWithoutExtension = fullName();
int lastDot = fullName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (lastDot >= 0) {
    nameWithoutExtension = nameWithoutExtension.substring(0, lastDot);
}
```

Comment: and that I print a list of files that use System.out.println (?????);

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the file and Split the String with

```
String[] file = filename.Split("\\.");'
```

`file[0]` holds the basename, whereas `file[1]` holds the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   listOfFiles.get(index).getName()
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons IO has a class called `FilenameUtils`, which offers the method [`getBaseName(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName%28java.lang.String%29). Just hand in your file's path for the argument.